# Rearrange and delete fields with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need help creating a sed command that will rearrange the fields in the file down below so that they are separated by a colon and their order is rearranged to this, `state:lastName:restOfName:city` (the street address gets dropped).

```
Mickey Mouse, 1111 Disney Dr., Orlando FL 
Minnie Mouse, 1112 Disney Dr., Anaheim CA
Adam Voter, 902 Biscayne Blvd., Miami FL
```

They are supposed to look like this when they are done.

```
FL:Mouse:Mickey:Orlando
CA:Mouse:Minnie:Anaheim
FL:Voter:Adam:Miami
```

This is homework and I can only use sed.

Comment: what did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service, you need to have at least tried something yourself...http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Sorry for not responding immediately. I am trying to get all of the spaces and other stuff removed using something like this sed -e 's/, /:/g' -e 's/ /:/g' -e 's/\.//g' thing.

Comment: Hint: you might want to remove the street address first.

Comment: @Matt Have you tried my solution? :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following sed command, let me know if you need additional explanations about it:

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/^([^\s]*)\s+([^,]*),[^,]*,\s*([^\s]*)\s+([^\s]*)\s*$/\4:\2:\1:\3/g' test_add_file.in;
```

**TESTED on:**

[image]

In a nutshell, you are define a regex that `sed` will use to look in your text file to fetch the required patterns, then you use `backreferences` to reuse the actual pattern that have been identified during the process.

For the exact syntax about the regex look at this link:

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Shortly:

- `^` beginning of line to fix the start of your pattern
- `([^\s]*)` is used to get your `Mickey, Minnie,...` (repetition of 0 to N non blank char that will are between parenthesis since this will be reused as back ref
- `\s+` 1 or more spaces between `Mickey and Mouse`
- `([^,]*)` will match the `Mouse` part of the string (repetition of 0 to N non comma char)
- `,[^,]*,\s*` part between the 2 commas that is not used `, 1112 Disney Dr.,`
- `([^\s]*)` used to fetch `Orlando, Anaheim`
- `\s+`    1 or more spaces between`Orlando and FL`
- `([^\s]*)` used to fetch `FL, CA, ...`
- `\s*$` fix the pattern end with `$` at `EOL` with eventually trailing spaces

then in the replacement part of your `sed` command you reorder the patterns and you put column between them by `\4:\2:\1:\3`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.